# Chrome Extension - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome.tabs API to run a script every time a tab is updated. The script searches for a keyword in the page and if it finds it, it alerts you, but if it doesnt, it refreshes the page. Whenever I test the extension, the console tells me:

[image: console error]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "keyword checker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "persistent":true,
      "page":"background.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "page_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

***background.html***

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

***background.js***

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo && changeInfo.status == "complete"){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "script.js"});
  }
});
```

***script.js***

```
if ($("div#wrap").is(":contains('comme')")) {
    alert('page contains keyword!');
  } else {
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated. I *have* included jquery in the root of the extension.

Comment: Do you know that `$` is the jquery function name ? Is that loading first ?

Comment: sound like this code is called before including jQuery

Comment: @A.Wolff I put jQuery before my background.js in the background.html file. Why would it do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have only included jQuery on your background page. You should be injecting jQuery onto the tab you're executing `script.js` on.

Here is an example that loads `jquery.js` first, then in a callback loads `script.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo && changeInfo.status == "complete"){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.js"}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "script.js"});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Another question, how would include a jquery plugin in the background.js? Would it be the same principle?

Comment: @user3376905 Just load the plugin script after jquery in a callback the same way.

Comment: Do I need to inject it every time I call `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or can I load it globally? I tried to include it into my `manifest.json`without success: `"js": ["content.js", "vendor/jquery-2.1.4.js"]`

Answer (score 0):

**In my case, Issue was file path.**

```
    {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "description" : "XYZ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "action" : {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["./jquery.js", "./popup.js" ]
        } 
    ],
    "icons" : {
        "16": "/images/favicon-16x16.png",
        "32": "/images/favicon-32x32.png",
        "48": "/images/android-icon-48x48.png"
    }
}
```