# Chrome extrension - chrome.tabs.executeScript doesnt run with file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to run code when some press my icon in my chrome extension. When i used to run the code with code: "code..." it changed the title but didn't run the jquery code. I read that you need to execute it from a file so i added a file. Now both of them doesn't work, before the title was changed (when i used code) and now (when i use the file) it doesn't work. I added alerts to see what code run, none of them work, not even the first

I got the following app:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Pandora Likes",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/19x19.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Pandora Likes"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs","http://*/","https://*/"]
}
```

background.js:

```
function onClick() {
chrome.tabs.query({},function(array_of_Tabs) {
    for(var i=0;i<array_of_Tabs.length; i++){
        if(array_of_Tabs[i].url.indexOf('pandora.com')> -1) {
            //chrome.tabs.update(array_of_Tabs[i].id, { selected: true });
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(array_of_Tabs[i].id,{file: "like.js"});
        }

    }
});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClick);
```

like.js:

```
alert("before");
document.title='gaga';
alert('after');
console.log("before);
$('.thumbDownButton').click();
console.log("after);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems here.

1. Your [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) (`http://*/`) only match URLs with blank paths. I.e. you would match `http://example.com/` but not `http://example.com/test/`.

   You can fix that with a single match pattern `*://*/*` (matches http or https) or even `<all_urls>`. Or, since you're only looking for Pandora, `*://*.pandora.com/*`.
2. Your `like.js` has a syntax error, made obvious by the syntax highlighting here on SO. You forgot a closing `"` on lines 4 and 6.
3. To use `$` in your context script, you need to [include jQuery first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544277/chrome-extension-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined) even if it's present on the page, since context scripts are [isolated from the page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). (Chrome has a console-only version of `$`, but it is also unavailable to content scripts)
4. Even if you *do* include jQuery, triggering `click()` might not lead to what you expect. Again, since the content script is isolated, the click handler lives in the page context and may* not be triggered by your code. Consider [injecting code into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

Please note: you should spend some effort debugging your extension yourself. Chrome is usually helpful with its error messages; see background's page console via a link at `chrome://extensions/`, and content script's errors will appear in the tab's console.

---

* *May* not be triggered, because you can still create a DOM mouse click event to trigger the page's listeners, but I'm reasonably sure `.click()` will not do that.